# Slow tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I've written a simple GUI in python using pylabs and tkinter based on an example found here:
http://hardsoftlucid.wordpress.com/various-stuff/realtime-plotting/
used for sine wave generation.

Except I tweaked it to pull data through suds from a server on the internet. It's not working as I exactly anticipated as the GUI is somewhat slow. I think its due to the timer. I just started learning how to use matplotlib functions yesterday so I'm not aware of how every function works.

How can I speed it up? Right now the data comes in at 2-3 seconds which is fine, but I just want to increase the GUI responsiveness.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



plt.ion() # set plot to animated


url = "http://10.217.247.36/WSDL/v4.0/iLON100.WSDL" 
client = Client(url, username='ilon', password='ilon', location = 'http://10.217.247.36/WSDL/iLON100.WSDL')

read = client.factory.create('ns0:E_xSelect')
read['xSelect'] = """//Item[starts-with(UCPTname, "Net/MB485/MAIN POWER/Fb/PowerSum")]"""

ydata = [0] * 50
ax1=plt.axes()  

# make plot
line, = plt.plot(ydata)
plt.ylim([10,40])

# start data collection
    while True:  
    x = client.service.Read(read).Item[0].UCPTvalue[0].value #data stream
    x = float(x)
    ymin = float(min(ydata))-10
    ymax = float(max(ydata))+10
    plt.ylim([ymin,ymax])
    ydata.append(x)
    del ydata[0]
    line.set_xdata(np.arange(len(ydata)))
    line.set_ydata(ydata)  # update the data
    plt.draw() # update the plot
```

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here.  Can you reduce this to the absolute minimum needed to demonstrate your problem?  I suspect the answer is going to be threads.

Comment: I edited it. I'm not sure if I can cut anymore, the pylab module is embedded in the Tkinter gui.

Comment: also, don't use pylab if your are embedding, see http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html you can end up with conflicting main loops.

Comment: Ok I changed it to the pyplot equivalent. I think its much easier to read now. Please take a look at it :)

Comment: sorry, was sloppy in writing, the problem is pyplot (which is imported by pylab).

Comment: and the reason that you gui is non-responsive is that you only have one thread and it is being blocked (I assume) by the `client.service.Read(..)` call.  You need to push that work off to a thread and use call-backs to trigger the re-draw.

Comment: How would I do that? Do I start a daemon? I'm new to python gui's and callbacks.

Comment: I have not used tk so I can't do more than point you in that direction, sorry.

Comment: If you look at my edited code it avoids tkinter. I don't plan on embedding it in a tkinter module anymore. I just want the responsive graph by itself.